# Is naming a constant within a function the same as the passing argument bad practice?

Tags: swift

I am learning the swift programming language. I'm following the "Intro to App Development with Swift" by Apple. In the course I am instructed to make the question argument lowercase.

```
// The course's answer
func responseTo(question: String) -> String {

    let lowerQuestion = question.lowercased()

    if lowerQuestion.hasPrefix("where") {
        return "To the North!"
    } else if lowerQuestion == "where are the cookies?" {
        return "In the cookie jar!"
    } else {
        return "That really depends"
    }
}

// My answer
    func responseTo(question: String) -> String {
    // TODO: Write a response
    let question = question.lowercased()
        if question.hasPrefix("hello") {
            return "Why, hello there"
        } else {
    return "That really depends"
    }
}
```

The String question is being passed. My way of doing was to make a constant also named question. The course made a constant called lowerQuestion.

Is my way considered bad practice? Could this cause errors in a large scale application?

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new `question` constant effectively hides the `question` parameter, which means that you cannot access the parameter `question` anymore after the declaration of the `question` constant.

In this case, you don't need the parameter anymore, so it's fine to do this, but in more large-scale projects, you never know when your requirements are going to change, and when it becomes that you actually *need* the parameter `question` later in the method. It is more troublesome for you to change it when that happens.

In addition, having two variables with the same name generally is not a good idea. It is very easy for readers of your code to get confused between them, even if the compiler doesn't.

Comment: I appreciate the in-depth explanation on my question. Your response made it much clearer looking at it from a big picture perspective. As a new developer in training it can be slightly difficult to assess how larger applications and other programmers will handle the code.

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfectly valid thing to do! You can also declare variables with the same name if they're in different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is okay. But if you had a global variable with the same name, then it can cause mutations. It's probably best practice to be more descriptive with your variable names anyways.

Also, once you assign question = question.toLowerCase(), you will no longer be able to access your parameter's original value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad practice as long as you plan to use the name as you defined it locally and aren't planning on referencing the argument as received.  It's especially useful when safely unwrapping an Optional parameter.

For example:

```
func responseTo(question: String?) -> String {

    // Exit early if our parameter is nil
    guard let question = question else {
        return "What question?"
    }
    ...
}
```

Another example can be when using a URL (or any failable initializer), or when it's convenient to use the argument converted to some other type:

```
func process(url: String) {

    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        return // bailing early 
    }
    ...
}

func addThree(to number: String) throws {

    guard let number = Int(number) else {
        throw Error.notANumber
    }
    return number + 3
}
```

or when your parameter is the raw value of some enum:

```
enum Pet: String {
    case dog
    case cat
    case bird
}

var pets = [Pet]()

func add(newPet: String) {

    guard let newPet = Pet(rawValue: newPet) else {
        return
    }
    pets.append(newPet)
}
```